# Proper Data Type in SQL Server to store Scientific Notation value? (Ex. 10^3)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sqldatatypes

Say I have test results values for a lab procedure that come in as 10<sup>3</sup>. What would be the best way to store this in SQL Server? I would think since this is numerical data it would be improper to just store it as string text and then program around calculating the data value from the string.

Comment: If it's a real-valued number, just store it as a `REAL`.  Is there some reason not to?

Comment: Do you intend to do any calculations with the value (in queries, aggregates, reports, etc)?

Comment: Can't say I've ever worked with `REAL` data types in SQL Server. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @RBarryYoung Given the values are in scientific notation from a scientific lab procedure, I suspect the OP wants to keep track of both the raw value and its precision -- 1.0 x 10^3 isn't the same thing as 1000, or even 1.000 x 10^3.

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic The answer really depends on what kind of subsequent calculations you're doing with the value you're storing.  Are you doing the calculations in SQL Server or a client application?  What language is the client in, if any?  And I'm going to assume that preserving the precision and correct nubmer of significant figures is a requirement?

Comment: @JimDagg in what way is it *not* the same?

Comment: @RBarryYoung Annoyingly, precision.  Scientific calculations are weird -- we can only keep as many significant figures as we have certainty of them.  So, for example,  3 (3 x 10^0) times 12 (1.2 x 10^1) is 40 (4 x 10^1), not 36 (3.6 x 10^1), since 3 only has one significant figure, but 3.0 times 12 would be 36.  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significance_arithmetic)

Comment: @JimDagg I am not sure at this time if any calculations will be performed on the data. The value comes from a test procedure when a test strip is dipped in a solution and compared with a visual chart with values of 10^1 - 10^8. This value then must be captured in SQL Server. The Application will be written with ASP.NET. Our shop has primarily been a Windows Form Applications shop, with this being our first push into Web Development.

Comment: Oh!  Making sure I understand, the results you have are an exponent of 10 from 1 to 8?

Comment: @JimDagg According to my notes, values for 1 test are: <100, 10^2, 10^3, 10^4, 10^5, 10^6 & 10^7. Another test has the result values of: <10, 10^1, 10^2, 10^3, 10^4, 10^5.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your data in numeric calculations, it is probably best to represent your data using once of SQL servers native numeric data type. Since you show scientific notation, it is likely you will want to use either REAL or FLOAT.

Real is basically 7 decimal digits of precision and float has 15 digits of precision (at least this is how they are normally used). You can actually specify reduced precision for FLOAT, but in practice most people just use REAL in that case. REAL takes 4 bytes of storage, and FLOAT requires 8 bytes.

The other numeric types are for fixed decimal point arithmetic.

Comment: I see what you are saying Gary. I will have to double-check, but I don't believe at this time any calculations will be performed with this data. The value comes from a test procedure when a test strip is dipped in a solution and compared with a visual chart with values of 10^1 - 10^8. This value then must be captured in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers in scientific notation like this have three pieces of information:

1. The significand
2. The precision of the significand
3. The exponent of 10

Presuming we want to keep all this information as exact as possible, it may be best to store these in three non-floating point columns (floating-point values are inexact):

```
DECIMAL significand
INT precision (# of decimal places)
INT exponent
```

The downside to the approach of separating these parts out, of course, is that you'll have to put the values back together when doing calculations -- but by doing that you'll know the correct number of significant figures for the result.  Storing these three parts will also take up 25 bytes per value (17 for the `DECIMAL`, and 4 each for the two `INT`s), which may be a concern if you're storing a very large quantity of values.

---

Update per explanatory comments:

Given that your goal is to store an exponent from 1-8, you really only need to store the exponent, since you know the mantissa is always 10.  Therefore, if your value is always going to be a whole number, you can just use a single `INT` column; if it will have decimal places, you can use a `FLOAT` or `REAL` per Gary Walker, or use a `DECIMAL` to store a precise decimal to a specified number of places.

If you specify a `DECIMAL`, you can provide two arguments in the column type; the first is the total number of digits to be stored, while the second is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point.  So if your values are going to be accurate to the tenths place, you might create a column of `DECIMAL(2,1)`.  [SQL Server MSDN documentation: DECIMAL and NUMERIC types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)